# Shellscript clone repositories in a nested for loop

Tags: git, shell

So I wanted to clone multiple repository I just put it in a loop like this

```
#! /bin/sh
# Begin code

git_repo=('https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32cubemx.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/ncurses5-compat-libs.git' 
'https://aur.archlinux.org/google-chrome.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32pio.git')

aur_clone(){
    for repo in ${git_repo[@]}
    do
        git clone $repo
    done
}
aur_clone
```

But I also want to change current folder to the git folder during the loop so I do it like this

```
#! /bin/sh
# Begin code

git_name=('stm32cubemx' 'ncurses5-compat-libs' 'google-chrome' 'stm32pio')
git_repo=('https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32cubemx.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/ncurses5-compat-libs.git' 
'https://aur.archlinux.org/google-chrome.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32pio.git')

aur_clone(){
    for repo in ${git_repo[@]}
    do
        for name in ${git_name[@]}
        do
            git clone $repo
            cd "$name"
            cd ..
        done
    done
}
aur_clone
```

But everytime it loop the clone it keep printing file exist. I would like you guys show me where I'm wrong at my code so I can improve myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loops iterates over all the `git_repo`'s.

The second for loops though all the `git_names`. Instead off dubble looping, you should match both names with the right url.

You could however use some [shell param expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to seperate the git name from the url:

```sh
$ url='https://gitlab.com/example_repo.git'
$ echo "${url##*/}" | cut -f1 -d"."
example_repo
```

Using this, your script will become somthing like this;

```
#! /bin/sh
# Begin code

git_repo=('https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32cubemx.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/ncurses5-compat-libs.git' 
'https://aur.archlinux.org/google-chrome.git' 'https://aur.archlinux.org/stm32pio.git')

aur_clone(){
    # Move to the dir you want the folder
    cd /home/me/myCode

    for repo in ${git_repo[@]}
    do
        # Get repo name
        name=$(echo "${url##*/}" | cut -f1 -d".")

        # Clone
        git clone $repo $name
    done
}
aur_clone
```

```
/home/me/myCode
/home/me/myCode/stm32cubemx
/home/me/myCode/ncurses5-compat-libs
...
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the link mates it worked and I just found a new command `cut` which is awesome